# Largest eigenvalue of a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $0\leq P\leq I$ is some positive semidefinite matrix. Here $A\leq B$ implies that $B-A$ is positive semidefinite.

For a positive semidefinite $X$, can the largest eigenvalue of $PXP$ be larger than the largest eigenvalue of $X$? If not, how can one show this?

---

My proof idea:

Let $x$ be the normalized eigenvector of $X$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. Then $x^*Xx \geq y^*Xy$ for any normalized $y$. In particular, $y^*PXPy = zXz$, where $z = Py$. Since $y^*y = 1$, we have $z^*z = yP^2y \leq y^* I y = 1$. So $\|z\|_2 \leq 1$. From this, we conclude that $x^*Xx \geq y^*PXPy$ for all normalized $y$ and hence the maximum eigenvalue cannot increase.

I did not use the positive semidefiniteness of $X$ in the proof and this is concerning because a projection can increase the maximum eigenvalue of a negative definite matrix. So I think something is wrong with the proof which leaves the original question still open.

Comment: Can you define the relation you use on matrix ( $0\leq P\leq I$ ) ?

Comment: @EtienneBfx, done - thanks for pointing that out

Comment: *can the largest eigenvalue of  be larger than the largest eigenvalue of ?*  Since $P$ and $X$ are each Hermitian positive semi-definite, the 'nice way' to do this is to notice eigenvalues coincide with singular values, then use submultiplicativilty of the operator 2 norm, i.e. $\lambda_{max}\big(PXP\big) =\big \Vert PXP\big\Vert_2 \leq \big \Vert P\big\Vert_2  \big \Vert X\big\Vert_2  \big \Vert P\big\Vert_2 \leq \big\Vert X\big\Vert_2 =\lambda_{max}\big(X\big)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $x^*Xx \geq y^*Xy$ for all $x$ and $y$ normalized vector.
But on your proof $z = Py$ can be $0$ which is non-normalizable.
A concrete example take $X = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$. $e_1$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $-1$ the largest eigenvalue.
Then taking $P=0$ we have $PXP=0$ with largest eigen value $0$ and $z=P e_1 =0$ is not "normalizable".

Comment: I see. Am I right to say that the statement holds when $X$ is positive semidefinite because this problem of $z = 0$ then will not matter?

Comment: Yes you will have $x^*Xx \geq max(0,y^*PXPy)$ for all normalized $y$, which give you your result.